# RN - Axios - How to add an axios interceptor in saga - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios, redux-saga

The code snippet in saga looks like this

```
function* addAmount(action) {


    try {
        const response = yield call(axios.get, RECHARGE_IP + 'api/createpaymentorder?username=' + action.username + '&amount=' + action.amount,{}, {
            headers: {
                'authorization': action.token,
            }
        })

        yield put({ type: ADD_MONEY_INITIATE_SUCCESS, data: response });

    }
    catch (e) {

        yield put({ type: ADD_MONEY_INITIATE_FAILURE, error: e });
    }
}
```

how can i attach a axios response interceptor with this so that i could check whether the token is expired or not and if expired i'll have to send refresh token to get new access token. How can i use axios interceptor in this scenario ?

---

### solved it myself the code is as follows

```
async componentDidMount() {

  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(REFRESH_TOKEN);
    if (value !== null) {
      // We have data!!
      console.log(value);
      this.setState({
        refreshToken: value
      })
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // Error retrieving data
  }
  //running interceptor
  const self = this;
  axios.interceptors.response.use(function(response) {
    // Do something with response data
    // console.log('response in interceptor', response);
    return response
  }, function(error) {
    const originalRequest = error.config;
    // Do something with response error
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    console.log('error==================================', error.response.data.error);


    if (error.response.status === 401 && error.response.data.error === 'invalid_token') { //custom error checking based on the data i get

      console.log('hit error');

      originalRequest._retry = true
      const retryOrigReq = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios.post(REFRESH_TOKEN_URL, null) //give ur refrsh token url 
          .then((resp) => {
            // console.log(resp)
            self.setState({
              token: resp.data.access_token
            });
            try {
              AsyncStorage.setItem('AUTH_TOKEN', 'bearer ' + resp.data.access_token);
            } catch (error) {
              // Error saving data
            }
            try {
              AsyncStorage.setItem('REFRESH_TOKEN', resp.data.refresh_token);
            } catch (error) {
              // Error saving data
            }
            originalRequest.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + resp.data.access_token
            resolve(axios(originalRequest));
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          })
      });
      return retryOrigReq;
    } else {
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: i solved it myself by adding an interceptor to the root file in the project and it worked , i haven't tested it much but initial results were positive

Comment: do you have maybe some code to see?

Comment: @VictorCastilloTorres sure , https://jsfiddle.net/sajanthomas01/ak9hftpy/1/

Answer (score 4):

You need to add an **axios** instance separately, add an **interceptor** on that and use that instance on other parts of your app.

### Interceptor.js

```
import axios from 'axios'
import {SERVER_URL} from '../Config'
import {path} from 'ramda'

import AuthService from './AuthService' // ... Just a service to refresh auth tokens

const AxiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: SERVER_URL,
    timeout: 20000,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
})

AxiosInstance.interceptors.response.use((response) =>{
    return response;
}, (error) => {
    const originalRequest = error.config;
    if (!error.response) {
       return Promise.reject('Network Error')
    }
    else if ((error.response.status === 401) && !originalRequest._retry) {
        originalRequest._retry = true;
        return AuthService.getToken()
            .then(token => {
                const authTokenResponse = path(['data', 'response'], token)
                AxiosInstance.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + authTokenResponse;
                originalRequest.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + authTokenResponse;
                return axios(originalRequest);
            })
            .catch(err => err)
    } else {
        return error.response
    }

})

export default AxiosInstance
```

### Services.js

```
import AxiosInstance from './Interceptor' // ... Your Interceptor path
const register = (params) =>
    AxiosInstance.get('// Some Sample Url')
        .catch(error => error) // Either handle the error here or in the sagas
```

### Sagas.js

Then in your sagas access the services.

Answer (score -2):

```
async componentDidMount() {

  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(REFRESH_TOKEN);
    if (value !== null) {
      // We have data!!
      console.log(value);
      this.setState({
        refreshToken: value
      })
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // Error retrieving data
  }
  //running interceptor
  const self = this;
  axios.interceptors.response.use(function(response) {
    // Do something with response data
    // console.log('response in interceptor', response);
    return response
  }, function(error) {
    const originalRequest = error.config;
    // Do something with response error
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    console.log('error==================================', error.response.data.error);


    if (error.response.status === 401 && error.response.data.error === 'invalid_token') { //custom error checking based on the data i get

      console.log('hit error');

      originalRequest._retry = true
      const retryOrigReq = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios.post(REFRESH_TOKEN_URL, null) //give ur refrsh token url 
          .then((resp) => {
            // console.log(resp)
            self.setState({
              token: resp.data.access_token
            });
            try {
              AsyncStorage.setItem('AUTH_TOKEN', 'bearer ' + resp.data.access_token);
            } catch (error) {
              // Error saving data
            }
            try {
              AsyncStorage.setItem('REFRESH_TOKEN', resp.data.refresh_token);
            } catch (error) {
              // Error saving data
            }
            originalRequest.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + resp.data.access_token
            resolve(axios(originalRequest));
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          })
      });
      return retryOrigReq;
    } else {
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Again, *do not post your code as an answer*. Click on the "edit" link below the question and put it there.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20726847)